# Swift animate UIButton background images

Tags: swift, animation, uiview

I have a UIButton that shows an image.  When the button is tapped I want to show a checkmark and then animate back to the original image.  I've never worked with animation so hopefully, you can help.  With the code below I do get 1 and 2 in my debug window, but the "1st" image doesn't show up or displays way too fast.  I have played with all the value and can't seem to get the proper values.  So basically, you tap the button, `circle_150px_green filled copy` shows (checkmark), what a short duration, and original button image `out of country` shows...

Thanks in advance.

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 25.0, delay: 0.0, animations: {
        //add keyframes
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 10.0, animations: {
            print("1")
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "circle_150px_green filled copy"), for: .normal)
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
            print("2")
            sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "out of country"), for: .normal)
        }

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Use the completion block to start another animation cycle to cycle back to it's desired state

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought the point of `UIView.animateKeyframes` was you didn't have to use the completion block to start another animation cycle.

Comment: Please forgive me, my understanding of the animation system is limited in this respect and you may be right on that point